# Reading excel file with JET OleDB C# ignoring first blank column

Tags: ado.net, oledb, oledbdatareader

I have an app that's reading in excel data using JET/ACE OleDB in C#. I'm using column numbers stored in the database to read in the data from these sheeets.

Everything work fine, except for one file in particular that has a blank first column (why they choose to leave it blank is beyond me). ADO.Net is ignoring the first column, and it's throwing everything out of whack. If I type anything into a cell in the first column this problem goes away, but is there any other workaround?

FYI
IMEX is set to 1, TypeGuessRows is set to 0 and ImportMixedTypes is set to Text in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

This seems somewhat related to this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010634/why-is-first-empty-line-ignored-in-excel-import-with-oledb)

What happens if you format the data in the spreadsheet explicitly as text? Is the first Column still ignored?